# Link images to slides using Google Slides script

Tags: slideshow, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have a presentation which include 3/4 inserted images on each slide.
the images are all in different positions via scripts.

I’m currently trying to link the images to a slide or two after the current one its on.
similar to the link  option when right clicking the images.

*e.g:
image 1 on slide [0] links to slide [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rE2v.png)

image 2 on slide [0] links to slide [3](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Elq5jEvynVCZWRIAwTCHOkLkRfjJ3X0Yg-NTlu9ozfs/edit?usp=sharing)

image 3 on slide [0] links to slide [3](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Elq5jEvynVCZWRIAwTCHOkLkRfjJ3X0Yg-NTlu9ozfs/edit?usp=sharing)*

This will then continue for the next slide as follows:

*e.g:
image 4 on slide [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rE2v.png) links to slide [[3](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Elq5jEvynVCZWRIAwTCHOkLkRfjJ3X0Yg-NTlu9ozfs/edit?usp=sharing)]

image 5 on slide [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rE2v.png) links to slide [4]

image 6 on slide [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rE2v.png) links to slide [3](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Elq5jEvynVCZWRIAwTCHOkLkRfjJ3X0Yg-NTlu9ozfs/edit?usp=sharing)*

the outcome will need to allow the image number/id (pageElement) **and** the slides index to be continuously editable.

Is this possible and if so, any input would be appreciated.
I’m a newbie at scripting and have tried a few alternatives with no personal outcome.
Here is a [sample](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Elq5jEvynVCZWRIAwTCHOkLkRfjJ3X0Yg-NTlu9ozfs/edit?usp=sharing) with the positions script and a few sites/options explored/looked at.
Thank you

- Selection.getPageElementRange

- Select a page element

  - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/selecting#select_a_page_element

- Cursor selection in a shape

  - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/selecting#cursor_selection_in_a_shape
- Selecting multiple page elements

  - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/selecting#selecting_multiple_page_elements
- Selecting a page element

  - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/selecting#selecting_a_page_element
- getSelectionType()

  - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/selection#getselectiontype

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by getting the images from the slide and setting a link slide for each particular image:

For example, to set `image 1 on slide [0] links to slide [1]`:

```
SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0].getImages()[0].setLinkSlide(1);
```

**References:**

[Class Presentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation)

[getImages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getimages)

[setLinkSlide(slideIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#setlinkslideslideindex)

Comment: Hello CMB, please excuse my really late reply but this was what I was looking for thanks.

Comment: Hello CMB, unfortunately the answer provided worked closer to the time the question was asked. Please see edited question if you have a moment. Thanks